# What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?

Tags: support, faq, user-interface

On Stack Overflow, there are many color codes.

Sometimes the number of votes on a question are highlighted with certain colors. Sometimes the background of the question or answer text is highlighted.

What do these colors mean?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

Comment: This questions and the upvotes it has received are indicative that the meaning of the colours (and/or the methods to find out the meaning of the colours) are not obvious enough, especially to new users.  Time to strip some colours or add more tool tips or something else to fix this.

Comment: Been using Stack Overflow for years and remained clueless as to the meaning of the beige background. I agree with @DavidHAust

Comment: I didn't know there were tooltips until now.  (It doesn't help that the color coding is different in different stackexchange forums.  I'm not arguing against forum-specific colors, but it places additional burden on each forum to make the meaning of colors clear.)

Comment: A lot of the meanings can be found by opening the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (right click, _Inspect Element_). Often the class names are semantically chosen and, together with the CSS rules, they reveal the meaning behind certain colors. E.g. `.owner` is used for the background color of the OP, `.answered-accepted` is used for vote indicators for which the corresponding question has an accepted answer. Furthermore, this trick can be used to learn the names of several patterns and technologies accross the web.

Answer (score 448):

The colors are designed to draw the user's attention to certain features of the site.

### Colors on the answer count in the question list:

- The black text means that the question currently has no answers.

  [image]
- The green text on a white background means that the question has at least one answer, but not an accepted answer.

  [image]
- The white text on a green background means that an "accepted answer" was chosen.

  [image]

### Colors in the background of a question summary in the question list:

- Creme-colored, "highlighted" questions contain one watched tag that is not explicitly queried; the highlighting is possible only if there are no search criteria other than tags ([clarification here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387796/unclear-faq-about-creme-colored-highlighted-questions)).

  [image]
- Faded questions contain one of your ignored tags.

  [image]
- Questions containing both watched and ignored tags will be faded (with or without the creme color, depending on the criteria explained above).

  [image]

### Colors on the background of a question, answer or comment:

- Answers to questions which are accessed directly using a permalink or by the redirect right after you submit a question glow with an orange background for a few seconds.

  [image]
- Answers with score of -3 (-8 on Meta) or lower get light gray text color and so are all comments made on such answers:

  [image]
- A blue background on the user information box in the lower-right corner of the answer indicates an answer posted by the asker of the question. The same holds true for comments.

  [image: Answer by the OP.]

  [image: Comment by the OP.]
- Accepted answers are indicated by the green checkmark below their score.

  [image]
- A greyish red background indicates the post is deleted. Deleted posts are only visible to the answer owner (i.e. the answerer), moderators, and users with more than 10k reputation.

  [image]
- A blue background in a revision item means that it was done by the original poster:

  [image]

### Colors on election pages

- Election entries of withdrawn candidates are faded out.

  [image]

### Colors on moderator tools

- In the delete votes list, posts that you are not eligible to cast delete votes on are faded out. These links are accompanied by a title text explaining this. For example, answers will appear like this to users who have the [Access to moderator tools privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), but not the [Trusted user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), and as a result cannot vote to delete answers.

  [image: Answers and some questions are faded out to an opacity level of 35%; the title text “you can’t vote to delete/undelete this post” appears.]

### Other known colorations

- View counts and comment scores both have dynamic text color based on the value they represent, going from ordinary gray to bright orange. Class names are `cool`, `warm`, `hot`, and `supernova`.

  Example for comments:

  [image: Screenshot of different example comments with different upvote counts; the counts are colored more brightly orange the higher the upvote count is.]

Comment: I think if an answer has only received down votes it appears greyed out. If it then gets an upvote it goes back to full black. If that's right it would be useful in telling whether a bad answer has gained a net positive rep.

Comment: As for that bug: Sam152 added a screenshot of blue text on a green background at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/why-are-the-number-of-upvotes-on-an-answer-sometimes-blue

Comment: Has the blue background been removed? I answered and accepted my own answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816168/receive-xml-via-post-with-asp-net and there is no blue background on Chrome or IE8, whether I am logged in or not.

Comment: @Matteo: Nice work, now we just need a [great edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42882/rep-for-editing/42998#42998) button.

Comment: Question summaries in the list are not highlighted if the list has been filtered by one of your favourite tags and those questions are not tagged with any of your other favourite tags.

Comment: Great answer. However, shouldn't there be an official link on the main page (questions page) to this kind of information? Named "conventions used on this page" or the like.

Comment: Is there any way to see if you have already given an answer to a question in the "Vote count" on the "question list"?

Comment: @jokklan nope, such thing does not exist at the moment.

Comment: Could you possibly change the image used for _The blue background on the user information box..._? I feel that because the avatar in that image happens to have a blue background, it makes it confusing for new users.

Comment: @aug it's not an image, it's a plain background color and it's different for every site.

Comment: I'd like to backup @DavidHAust comment on the OP regarding the difficulty to find those kind of information.
Tried to find "yellow and white question stackoverflow" on google yesterday... but found nothing useful (even tough my search terms may have been incorrect).
I only found this post today after looking at "orange background stackoverflow" and even there the first result was actually this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130510/why-do-some-questions-have-an-orange-background-and-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-new leading to here.

Wouldn't it be easier to have those in the tour?

Comment: Some people see Creme color as Yellow

Comment: Please also add the shading applied to the user's information box if they have filled the about me

Comment: @Yatin That shading appears to have been removed now.

Comment: @Cerbrus What is the reason for [this rollback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/281741/12)?

Comment: You added curly quotes, removed `-` signs from vote counts and shortened urls, which means you don't see the question't title when you hover over it, @user4642212. If you want to add information, don't apply bad practices like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus _“removed - signs from vote counts”_ — I didn’t. I replaced them by the U+2212 Minus sign, which is the correct symbol to use here. I also don’t see what’s wrong with curly quotes and curly apostrophes. They’re the preferred symbols.

Comment: @user4642212: SO uses the hyphen to indicate negative numbers. (Even in that specific area the example is talking about). Curly quotes may be preferred by you, but they're commonly ___not___ used on SO, and [generally discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285248/are-smart-quotes-acceptable-in-edits).

Answer (score 27):

## *Updated late 2016*

### Colors on the “Answer Count” in the question list:

- The black text means that the question currently has no answers.

  [image: No answers]
- The green outline means that the question has at least one answer, but not an accepted answer.

  [image: Answers but one not accepted]
- The white text on a green background means that an “accepted answer” has been chosen.

  [image: Answer has been accepted]

### “Hotness” colorations

- View counts and comment scores both have dynamic text color based on the number they represent, going from ordinary gray to bright orange. Class names are `cool`, `warm`, `hot`, and `supernova`.

  Note that the colors are based on the exact value, [not on the displayed, rounded value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339784).

  [image: View counts have different shades of orange]

### Colors in the background of a question summary in the question list:

- Creme colored, “highlighted” questions contain one of your interesting / watched tags.

  [image: Interesting / watched tags]
- Faded questions contain one of your ignored tags.

  [image: Ignored tag]
- Questions which are both creme colored and faded contain both interesting and ignored tags.

  [image: Questions with both interesting and ignored tags]

### Colors on the background of a question or answer:

- Answers to questions which are accessed directly using a permalink or by the redirect right after you submit a question glow orange.

  [image: Glowing submitted answer]
- Answers with score of -3 or lower (-8 on Meta) become transparent (resulting in light gray text) and so are all comments made on such answers. The answer can be hovered to gain full opacity again:

  [image: Answers with a negative score]
- A blue background on the user information box in the lower-right corner of the answer indicates an answer posted by the asker of the question. The same holds true for comments.

  [image: Answer by the asker]
- Accepted answers are indicated by the green checkmark next to them.

  [image: Accepted]
  *Accepted answer tick*
- A greyish red background indicates the post is deleted. Deleted posts are only visible to the answer owner (i.e. the answerer), moderators, and users with more than 10k reputation.

  [image: Deleted answer as seen by the answerer]

### Colors on Stack Overflow Jobs:

- Highlighted jobs are a [paid product](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/206822/289905).

  [image: Highlighted jobs in the job list]

Comment: According to http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color, the “grayish red” could approximately be called “Soft Peach”. I like that. The “creme” however would be called “Island Spice”. Not sure about that one…