# Why the "useful comment" count showing in different color

Tags: discussion

I noticed a few "useful comment" counts are showing in orange color [as per the below screen shot], hope those have more number of votes received.

[image: Useful comments count]

I want to know, after having received how many number of votes, the "useful comment" count will be showing in orange color.

Comment: See this [MSE answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85847/280467).

Comment: Doesn't it look pretty after you become popular? It's like a golden crown! :)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean/281741#281741) but doesn't answer *"after received how many number of votes, the "useful comment" count will be showing in orange color."*

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I see for some of the questions `"min":30,"max":500,"setIsValid":a`, is the `max` is varying for each question?

Comment: @Arulkumar not sure.  I think it might be per-site.