# Green/White icons indicating accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

This is about the green/white icons in the question and answer lists in the profiles. I've been here two years and I still don't remember what the green and white mean. It's a terrible design and really should be better.

[image]

Of course I figured it out: The green means that the question has an accepted answer and the white means it doesn't (or is it the other way, I can't remember).

There would be a perfectly easy fix. Hopefully easy.

[image: New question icons]

In the question list (not in the profile) green means at least one answer is present.

In the profile in question section green means there is an accepted answer. But in the answer section green means my answer was accepted

If you're in the summary then only a basic icon is used. But in the profile question list it is also indicated by white or yellow whether an answer was accepted.

With so many definitions of what green means it's quite complicated. Why not stick with one definition of green? And if it takes so much thought to figure it out then it is just bad. No other way to put it.

[Don't Make Me Think! A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability by Steve Krug](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321965515)

Comment: I'm not surprised if the long time users of this site like it the way it is because that's what they're used to. But that doesn't mean it's good design. At least not according to Steve Krug.

Comment: I don't know about Steve Krug, but as far as I'm concerned the proposed design is much worse. The colors symbolics of the current mode may be perfectible (although I'm actually ok with them) but I would be horrified to find out they've been replaced with tiny unreadable checkmark icons.

Comment: @EricD. Maybe so but I hope someone comes up with something better. I just know it's bad.

Comment: Apparently this is a common question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean There's gotta be a better way.

Answer (score 7):

This is going to *really* mess with your head...but...

- White indicates that there are *no* answers at all on a given question.
- A green background indicates that there are answers on a question, but none of them have been accepted.
- A green background with yellow text indicates that there are answers *and* one has been accepted.

The hover text over that box also says as much.

I don't agree with the proposed design since I personally see it as a bit too cluttered.

Comment: In the profile summary tab, there's no green+white combo, for some reason; questions with unaccepted answers show up as just white, same as unanswered.

Comment: I should have been more explicit in my question but I'm referring to the icons in the profile lists. I assumed that was obvious from the icons themselves.

Comment: This answer is only true for the question list. But does not apply to the answer list.

Comment: Also I don't get hover text in the profile summary page.

Comment: I agree. Simply having the number of answers on a post and a white background is plenty of visual info; we can read numbers here so we shouldn't be forced to discern between forest green and pale green to determine acceptance.