# What is mean of Block-quote questions while browsing question asked by other user

Tags: support, outdated-information

I am just looking for question to help other issue but when I am browsing question there are some questions which are Blockquoted what does they indicate.

[image]

Can anyone let me know meaning of Block-quoted questions.

Comment: Do you mean the questions in yellow?

Comment: yes. yes. yes. yes

Comment: This is why coloring blockquotes yellow was a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

The color/highlight indicates that the question contains one or more of your favorite tags.

If you are viewing all questions tagged with a specific tag and that tag is one of your favorite tags, only questions with other tags that is of your favorite tags will be highlighted. For example if your favorite tags are `javascript`, `grails` and `html`, and you are viewing questions tagged `grails`, only questions tagged with `html` and `javascript` will be highlighted.

[See this answer for more details.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281741/5305938)

Comment: But you observe picture you will find `grails` tag below to the `Blockquoted` question.

Comment: @SohamShetty How do you mean?

Comment: Cause I know selected tag is `grials`

Comment: @SohamShetty Is `grails` one of your favorite tags?

Comment: @SohamShetty Updated, see if you understand now.

Comment: Yes. I have selected `grails` tag while browsing questions.

Comment: May be but not sure