# Why aren't questions with my tags highlighted when I filter questions?

Tags: support, tag-watching

On the Stack Overflow homepage, questions that have tags you're interested in are highlighted, e.g. I like `linux` and `matlab`:

[image]

And yet, other tags that're also in my tags list, such as `fortran` and `fortran90` aren't highlighted for me when I filter the question list unless a question is tagged with 2 or more of them. Here's an example of this:

[image]

I've looked around and done some searching on Meta for more specific rules on more precise criteria for whether a question gets highlighted, but I've not found anything.

**NOTE:**  I revised this question significantly (at around 2016-12-19 23:55Z) in response to comments below, so older comments may no longer make sense in context.

Comment: Are the Fortran tags in your favorite tags list?

Comment: Yes, clarifying question now.

Comment: For the second screenshot, are you filtering on the fortran tag?

Comment: @approxiblue Yes, I didn't see any on the home page at the time.

Comment: When you filter on the [fortran] tag, those questions don't get highlighted; however, if they have additional tags you marked as favorite (in this case [fortran90]), then those will be highlighted.

Comment: @approxiblue Good find, my searching didn't return that.  Mine was this from that answer "Note that when viewing a question list within one or more of your interesting tags, only questions with one or more additional interesting tags will be highlighted."  I can't find a specific question for this (although a couple are close), so maybe the best way to deal with this is to revise the question to ask: Why aren't questions with my tags highlighted when I filter questions?  And then answer with an explanation and a reference to that page.

Comment: @approxiblue Better yet, let's continue in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130986/chat-re-why-does-stack-overflow-think-i-dont-like-fortran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comments by other users and [this answer to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281741/1789543) a [more general question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) that approxiblue found, the reason for this is a matter of usability.  Questions are highlighted to emphasize them *relative to* the other questions around them.  So, on the main page, questions that have any of your tags are highlighted.  But when you filter by one of your favorited tags, then only questions that have 2 or more of your favorite tags will be highlighted, since highlighting every question on the page would be useless.