# Delay highlight for when the page is focused

Tags: feature-request, design

Could we wait for the page to be focused to show the effect?

It's a very simple feature request, but this would be useful for when you open new tab(s) and the effect is already gone.

**"The effect":**

[image: Demonstration of the effect.]

**Try it out:**

Open both answers below in new tabs, wait a couple of seconds and go visit them.

- [One answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281741/4577762)
- [Another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean/336810#336810)

Comment: For trying it out I suggest you also visit a page directly to see the difference.

Comment: @AndréKool Of course ;). I was assuming people using SO were already familiar with it.

Comment: For me it's a case of: I have seen it so many times I don't notice it anymore.