# Why are some job ads colored differently?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, design

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, some jobs in the jobs listing have a yellow (Corn Silk) colored background while others do not. I tried to find any logic into why some jobs are colored different than others but couldn't find any.

Can someone explain to me why we have two different colors for job adds and what the message is the yellow background is trying to convey?

I'm also curious to know if I am the only one that finds this "random" coloring of job adds puzzling. If others think it is unclear as well what can be changed to improve the user experience?

Comment: What are your "Watched Tags" ?

Comment: Just javascript and vue.js.

Comment: Good question; the CSS class is just called `_highlighted` and it doesn’t seem to correlate with watched tags.

Comment: It seems to correlate with proximity to location, benefits (paid relocation, working remote), tags and more for me. I suspect there is some kind of _goodness of fit_ algorithm at work, but guess only an employee can answer.

Comment: The highlighting is not reflected in the XML of the RSS feed. It only highlights about 2 to 4 jobs per page for me, and I don’t use SO Jobs. I guess “the algorithm” isn’t trained for my interests…?

Comment: My guess is it takes information from https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current, where you can enter a lot of data on jobs you're interested in. I don't suspect it's training/self-learning. All speculation, of course.

Comment: I just checked my Jobs listing, and the 1st entry was yellow-colored and *had a label "Featured" on the top-left*.

Comment: I guess that as an employer, you can pay some fee to make your offer highlighted. :-)

Comment: the yellow/orange background is probably related to your watched tags, or favourites

Comment: "Corn Silk"... [It's clearly Varden](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#FFF8DC)...

Comment: I have always skipped over the highlighted entries because they look like ads on google ("sponsored results")

Comment: This is now documented in [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336810/4642212).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Highlighted jobs are paid. This means that whoever offered the listing paid extra to have the job highlighted and advertised in search results.

[Per this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206821/what-does-the-highlighted-vs-non-highlighted-posts-on-careers-mean)

Although this post was regarding the old Careers, it still proves to work the same way for the new Jobs. Whenever you use the Job search, a different, highlighted job will be at the top each time (Along with text saying `Featured`), those being the advertised ones.

Comment: That post refers to the old “careers”, not The present “jobs”. Not entirely sure it’s the same thing and the same rules apply.

Comment: @yivi It does make sense as every time you use the Jobs search, a different highlighted job will show up at the top each time.