# Unclear FAQ about creme-colored/highlighted questions

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I am hereby humbly asking for clarification of this text in the FAQ "[What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281740/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)" (my question is not a duplicate of the FAQ, it asks to clarify one small part of it) :

> Creme-colored, "highlighted" questions contain one watched tag that is not explicitly queried; the highlighting is possible only if there are no search criteria other than tags.

If I display the questions which are tagged `abap` and contain the words `ALV refresh`, and among my watched tags is `sap`, I would expect that the questions tagged `sap` are highlighted with the creme color:

> [image: creme-colored/highlighted questions]

As you see, none of the questions are highlighted with the creme color, although they are assigned the tag `sap` that I watch:

> [image]

Can someone explain why (and clarify the FAQ), possibly with some examples?

Comment: I'm surprised by the quantity of "does not show any research effort". One month ago, the FAQ ("Creme colored, "highlighted" questions contain one of your favorite tags.") was incorrect because I had one question containing one of my watched tags, but it was not highlighted. Then I corrected the FAQ today, and I created this question to explain how it really works. How should I reword it please?

Answer (score -2):

Here are some examples for each case:

1. No search criterial at all -> highlight of questions which contain at least one watched tag
2. One or more tags searched (only) -> highlight of questions which contain at least one watched tag that is not searched
3. Use of search criteria other than tags -> no question is highlighted

---

## 1. No search criteria at all

If the user watches the tag `python-3.x` or `astropy` but not `reactjs` and `react-pdf`, only the first question below is highlighted:

[image: Question list - No search criteria at all]

NB: the corresponding "search" URL is https://stackoverflow.com/.

---

## 2. One or more tags searched (only)

Two examples, one with one tag searched, and one with two tags searched.

#### Questions tagged [tag]

If the tag `python-3.x` is searched, and the user watches the tag `csv` but not `python` and `excel` (and whatever `python-3.x` is watched or not), only the first question below is highlighted:

[image: Question list - One tag searched (only)]

NB: the corresponding search URL is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x.

#### All Questions tagged [tag1] or [tag2]

This example is not so different from the case with only one tag. Note that this example would also work if the search would concern questions containing both tags ("and-ed" tags using `[tag1] [tag2]`).

If questions with the tag `pycharm` or `reactjs` are searched, and the user watches the tag `javascript` but not `c#` (and whatever `pycharm` and `reactjs` are watched or not), only the first question below is highlighted:

[image: Question list - Two tags searched (only)]

NB: the corresponding search URL is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycharm+or+reactjs.

---

## 3. Use of search criteria other than tags

If the term `csv` is searched within questions of tag `python-3.x`, no question is highlighted, whatever the tags `csv`, `beautifulsoup` and `html-table` are watched or not -  The highlighting is inactive because some search criteria other than tags are used (here, the term `csv`) - In short, it's inactive in all "Search Results" views:

[image: Question list - Use of search criteria other than tags]

Comment: Why did you feel the need to post a new question when simply posting this as an answer to the other one would have sufficed?

Comment: @jhpratt Mine is one tiny aspect of the other question, I prefer to separate. The FAQ is a broad question, it's not forbidden to have other questions around it. If a question is broad, it's better to link to the details described & answered in other questions, that's a matter of hierarchization.