# What is the purpose of answer-accepting if it is one person's fast decision?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

The accepted answer can not be the best answer if question and answer is made at same time (there is a button for this) or if the answer is accepted too quickly as many do, because the best answers always come after a while of some time of effort, investigation and consideration from other answers.

Isn't the better answer often the second answer? If not the first accepted answer was blocking - the second could have been upvoted to the first place.

Is there a case or reason to have the acceptance functionality?

Comment: *"Is there any case or reason to have the acceptance functionality?"* - It puts a nice green box next to a question listing when a question has an accepted answer, allows you to filter on questions with the "hasaccepted:no" search filter and gives the person who wrote the answer a cool 15 points of reputation.

Comment: Sometimes fun game playing seem to have more value than quality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right,

> **[Populist:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist)** Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer
>   with a score of more than 10 by more than 2x **20k Awarded**

we have many answers which are better than the accepted answer which has been upvoted by the community

**Advantage of Quick Acceptance:**

Accepting answer will let others know that this issue has already been solved and tag watchers can focus on others question to answer them which may decrease the unanswered percentage rate

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now I understand "Accepting answer will let others know that this issue has already been solved". It was not very clear for me because I confused it with voting.

Comment: welcome @PauliSudarshanTerho, you may also find more details here what different colors mean https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281741/10961238

Comment: Somehow the green makes me klick despite it is solved more from the questioners perspective and maybe not the best answer

Comment: *"Accepting answer will let others know that this issue has already been solved"* - well, it would if askers reliably had the competence needed to judge if an answer even worked, and if we had coordinated as a community to ruthlessly stamp out the rather common practice of answerers harassing askers to mark their answers as accepted. Since neither of those things is true, acceptance unfortunately can't be counted on to mean much at all.

Answer (score 4):

You're right! This happens quite a bit. We have a name for this ["Fastest Gun in the West"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite), and there has been lots of ink spilled over it, and over its associated phenomena, [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207334/accepted-answers-best-answer-vs-good-answer).

Bottom line (to recap years of hashing out):

1. Accepting an answer is something only the author does; and it means the OP thought it was the best answer for them.
2. Votes mean what the collection of people think.

Answer (score -2):

Yes - the acceptation mark means this post solves the OP question - that their functionality - marking this post solves the problem. You are correct, it is not always the best way of solving the problem (do notice that on most of the times it is).

But for that we have the voting system - even if question was solve on one way, another answer, with different way can be more elegant, cover more edge case and so on - when you encounter this situation do as I do: **Up-vote the second post**. I also **add comment to the OP** saying they should probably switch the "Accepted answer" to the second one.

If you not fresh user in the site you already know to look at least in the first two answers when looking at question you searching for solution...

Comment: I accept your answer but may change. From what you tell, I now see the accepted answer may be in the special situation, but the second answer is from a general situation from the users.

Comment: It's rather ironic that this answer was accepted within minutes of accepting an answer being possible.

Comment: It is because I have a sense of humor ;)

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho moving the acceptance to the second answer which also have negative score is do hilarious... :D

Comment: May be - but it is because I wish that answer to be true

Comment: I fine with it - that the whole point of the acceptance - it answer your question then it can be mark as accepted even if it is not the best answer - as long as you get your answer I am satisfy

Comment: Also I know that the green marked hits is of more interest, so to attract more readers it can be good to accept the first to change later

Comment: Agreed - having accept the second best-answer is better than no acceptance at all (in my option) - that why I fine with OP marking first answer as accepted (if it solved their issue) and then change later (if because of people comment or by their own choose)

Comment: Comments suggesting a different answer should be accepted are usually picked up by the regex that enables single-flag deletion. The commenting part is not good advice, it adds noise. What OP accepts is entirely their choice, regardless of what might be better or more efficient