# Why do the colors in comment vote numbers differ?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

I know that the numbers represent the number of votes a comment has, but what do the colors denote? I've seen dark red, light orange and black.

But why would there need to be different colors? Why not just black for all of them?

Comment: It’s explained in [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281740/4642212), but what exactly are you asking? You know that the colors represent different vote “hotness”. What else is unclear?

Comment: Oh thanks for the quick response! But why would there need to be different colors? Why not just black for all of them?

Comment: To make it easier to visually distinguish between a high-voted comment and a low-voted comment. Colors are sometimes easier to see than numbers.